# Use return from a Future <String> as the title of the alert widget

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, i have a method that returns a String from the firebase:

```
 Future<String> getNomeById(bool retirada, String userId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: userId)
        .getDocuments();

    users = snapshot.documents.map((d) => User.fromDocument(d)).toList();

    if (retirada) {
      name = users[0].name;
    } else {
      name = 'Other';
    }
    return name;
  }
```

Here I get the method return

```
u.getNomeById(retirada, userId).then((value) {
  returnFutureString = value;
  print(returnFutureString);//It's OK here
});
```

I need to use the return Future String in the title of my alertDialog,
I can't because my variable is null there, I know I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't make it work by searching for similar examples.

```
class ExportAddressDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  ExportAddressDialog(this.address, this.retirada, this.userId);

  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  final Address address;
  final bool retirada;
  final String userId;

  final ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String returnFutureString;
    Util u = new Util();

    u.getNomeById(retirada, userId).then((value) {
      returnFutureString = value;
      print(returnFutureString);//It's OK here
    });

    return AlertDialog(
      title:  Text(returnFutureString),//I need to use my returnFutureString  as the alert title, but is null here
      content: Screenshot(
        controller: screenshotController,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            '${address.street}, ${address.number} ${address.complement}\n'
            '${address.district}\n'
            '${address.city}/${address.state}\n'
            '${address.zipCode}',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            final file = await screenshotController.capture();
            await GallerySaver.saveImage(file.path);
          },
          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: const Text('Exportar'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Future<String> _getTitle() async {
    String returnFutureString = await u.getNomeById(retirada, userId)
    return returnFutureString;
  }
```

Use `FutureBuilder` to fetch async values:

```
  FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _getTitle(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(snapshot.data)
          );
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
  ),);
```